# formatting an interger64 object

Tags: r, printf

```
require(bit64)
a = c(500184833384,1803618000152,25053117000164)
b = as.integer64(a)

sprintf("%014.0f" ,a) # returns what I want/expected
# "00500184833384" "01803618000152" "25053117000164"

sprintf("%014.0f" ,b) # I don't understand this behavior
# "00000000000000" "00000000000000" "00000000000000"
```

### Background

I'm using `fread` from the `data.table` package to import data into `R`. Some fields are automatically read as `integer64` objects. I am trying to format those fields. In particular, I want them printed with a fixed width, padded with zeros to the left if necessary. I am trying to use with `sprintf`; I also tried `format`, which seems to have specific methods for `integer64` objects, but no luck there.

### Questions

How do I format an object of class `integer64`? In particular, how do I print that object with a fixed width, padded with zeros to the left if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's often useful to look at objects with `dput`:

```
> dput(b)
structure(c(2.47124142745862e-312, 8.91105692095995e-312, 1.23778844310223e-310
), class = "integer64")
```

So internally they are just very small numbers.

```
> cat(b)
2.471241e-312 8.911057e-312 1.237788e-310
```

But they have a print method:

```
> print(b)
integer64
[1] 500184833384   1803618000152  25053117000164
> sprintf("%014.0f" , print(b) )
integer64
[1] 500184833384   1803618000152  25053117000164
[1] "00000000000000" "00000000000000" "00000000000000"
```

Huh? Well, the print function gave its best attempt but sent the original value to sprintf as a numeric class object.

```
> sprintf("%014.0f" , as.character(b) )
Error in sprintf("%014.0f", as.character(b)) : 
  invalid format '%014.0f'; use format %s for character objects
> sprintf("%014.0s" , as.character(b) )
[1] "00000000000000" "00000000000000" "00000000000000"
```

Nuts. Needed to drop the decimal point formating for character class arguments:

```
> sprintf("%014s" , as.character(b) )
[1] "00500184833384" "01803618000152" "25053117000164"
```